# Passing each line of a file as command line argument to a binary file

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

I have a binary file :  **temp.exe**

This binary (**temp.exe**) takes two command line arguments **`a`** and **`b`**.

I also have a file **`agrsList.txt`**, which contains :

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
:  :
:  :
an bn
```

Now, I want to pass each line of this file as argument to the binary file.

**PS: I do not have access to the source code, so that I can edit the code and make it read the file.**

Is there a method to solve this problem **(without writing a script)**.

Comment: If the binary has no special provision to take its arguments from a file formatted exactly like that *and* you rule out writing a script, how would a hypothetical solution work? Magic?

Comment: This is more a bash question than a C or C++ one IMO

Comment: Well a script is just a bunch of **shell commands** only. If you want to write few commands on shell, you can also write a script, and that'd be better solution

Comment: 1) I have a file agrsList.txt; I want to pass each line of this file as argument to the binary file: Sure.  Easy.  2) I do not have access to the source code, so that I can edit the code and make it read the file: No problem.  3) Is there a method to solve this problem?  Sure.  WRITE A SCRIPT TO READ YOUR FILE AND CALL YOUR PROGRAM WITH THE NEXT PAIR OF ARGUMENTS!!!!!!

Comment: @Jon: I know the script solution. I just wanted to know, is there any direct command exist to do the same... :)

Comment: `while read; do temp $REPLY; done < argList.txt` - is that considered script?

Comment: Or better yet `xargs -a argsList.txt -n2 temp` but in theory it might feed arguments 1 by 1. But it shouldn't.

Comment: @Jon: See the solution given below (MAGIC .. :D). Don't comment, if you don't know the answer.

Comment: @Vivekanand: You realize that `xargs` is a "script" right? It's just written in C. Also, I don't know how it goes where you come from but around here speech (and commenting) is free.

Comment: @Jon: Anyways, I got my answer. Apologies for being rude. Be happy. .. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
    xargs -rn 2 temp.exe < agrsList.txt
```

The `-r` means `temp.exe` is only run if there are parameters.
The `-n 2` means `temp.exe` is run with at most two parameters.
If there is an odd number of words in `agrsList.txt`, then `temp.exe` will be run with just one parameter, the last one.

See [man xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) for further information.

Comment: Or use `-a agrsList.txt` instead of redirection.

Comment: Nominal Animal : Thanks. I was looking for something exactly like this.
@aragaer: Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @aragaer: Yes, `xargs -rn 2 -a agrsList.txt temp.exe` is probably the best approach here. The difference is that `-a agrsList.txt` causes `xargs` to read the arguments from that file, retaining standard input as normal for `temp.exe`. With redirection, `temp.exe` gets `/dev/null` for standard input; no user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Something this simple would normally be best handled by
a "scripting" language, but it's pretty straight foreward in
C++ as well.  If you're reading your file from standard in:

```
std::string args;
while ( std::getline( std::cin, args ) ) {
    system( ("temp " + args).c_str() );
}
```

should be all you need.  (But you don't say what you want to do
if `temp` fails.)